# Wordpress Contact form 7 set recipient from custom shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I can't get this to work. And it seems impossible to get any real documentation of the process.

I have a custom shortcode in my functions.php, which gets an email adress from an external API. I would like to use this shortcode in the "TO" (i.e. recipient) field in WPCF7. But it keeps giving me an error warning of "syntax error".

I need to find a way to make the recipient field accept a custom shortcode from my functions.php file.

I've tried [the dynamic text plugin](http://sevenspark.com/wordpress-plugins/how-to-dynamically-set-the-recipient-to-email-address-in-contact-form-7) but it doesn't work.

Here is an example of my shortcode

```
function single_email() {
    global $contact;
    return $contact->email;
}add_shortcode( 'contact_email', 'single_email' );
```

Maybe something along the line of using "wpcf7_special_mail_tags" and "do_shortcode()"? Not really sure how that works though.

Using Version 4.4.2 of WPCF7.

Comment: You mean you have to create `contact_email` shortcode right?

Comment: My bad! Yes, add_shortcode. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check below code?

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('contact_email', 'single_email', true);
function single_email(){
    global $contact;
    return $contact->email;
}
```

Comment: The error is simply "syntax error" for the "to" field. For good measure, Version 4.4.2 is my current WPCF version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this create new field in `wp_options` table and use like this.

**On Your Contact page**

```
      <div class="contant">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="contact_pannel">
          <h1>You can find us literally anywhere, just push a button and we’re there</h1>
          <div class="lf_pannel">
          <form action="" method="" id='myForm'  onsubmit=" return pretendValidation();  ">
            <h2>Use this form to send us a message:</h2>
            <div class="fild">
                <label class="label">Name</label>
                <input name="Name"   type="text" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="fild">
                <label class="label">Email</label>
                <input name="Email" type="email" class="input" required=required  >
            </div>

            <div class="fild">
                <label class="label">Company</label>
                <input name="Company" type="text" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="fild">
                <label class="label">Subject</label>
                <input name="Subject" type="text" class="input">
            </div>

            <div class="fild">
                <label class="label">Message</label>
                <textarea class="input" style="height:90px;" id='Message'></textarea>
            </div>
                <input name="submitt" type="submit" id="submitt" style="display:none;">

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="send_button margin_right23" onclick="document.getElementById('mailed').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('submitt').click();" >Send Message</a>
          </form>

          <div class="  wpcf7-display-none " id="mailed"   role="alert">Your message was sent successfully. Thanks.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="rg_pannel">


          <?php echo html_entity_decode(  get_option('admin_address') );?>





          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function pretendValidation(){


    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
        var fruit = 'Banana';
          // console.log($( "#myForm" ).serialize());
        // This does the ajax request

        $.post( "<?=get_template_directory_uri () ;?>/contact_ajax.php",
        { myForm: $( "#myForm" ).serialize(), Message: $( "#Message" ).val() },
        function( data ) {
          console.log( data ); // John

        });




         $('#myForm')[0].reset();

         $( "#mailed" ).show( "slow" );

    });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

After that you have to create ajax page like this

**contact_ajax.php**

```
<?php

/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once  ( '../../../wp-load.php' );

// echo "1232".site_url();


// print_r($_REQUEST);

$params = array();
parse_str($_REQUEST['myForm'], $params);
$params['Message']= $_REQUEST['Message'];
// print_r($params);

$to      = get_option('your_email_field_name');
// $to      = "demo@youremail.in";
$subject = 'Fokus Tech Contact Form';
  $message = "Hello,\n"
            ."Name: ".$params ['Name']."\n"
            ."Email: ". $params ['Email']."\n"
            ."Company: ".$params ['Company']."\n"
            ."Subject: ". $params ['Subject']."\n"
            ."Message: ".$params['Message'] ."\n"

;
$headers = 'From: no-repaly@you.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: no-repaly@you.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```